# ASP.NET Entity Framwork Connection String Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, mvp

Hey getting the following error when running my MVP Entity Framework App :

Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.

My Config is as follows :

```
    <add name="StevenTestEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=Data Source=D000097;
Initial Catalog=StevenTest;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The is occurring on the following method

```
        public StevenTestEntities() : base("name=StevenTestEntities", "StevenTestEntities")
```

Which is called in my Entity Designer Class.

Comment: -1 for neither putting effort into searching for the problem yourself nor asking a thoughtful, well written question.

Comment: Not really a duplication, as it is regarding the Entity Framework connection string format. Wasn't a very well formatted question to begin with, but it has been tidied up a bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you missing the `&quot;` from the connection string section.

Should be

```
<add name="StevenTestEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Data Source=D000097;
Initial Catalog=StevenTest;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Try that out.